# Initial values for some fields from db

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to put data from the database in the initial form?

```
def add_customer_from_list(request, pk):
    application = Contact.objects.get(pk=pk)
    params = {'name': application.name,
              'email': application.email,
              'phone_number': application.phone_number,
              'dog_name': application.dog_name,
              'service_type': application.service_type}
    form = CustomerForm(request.POST or None, initial=params)
    if form.is_valid():
        """form.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        form.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        form.phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
        form.address = form.cleaned_data['address']
        form.dog_name = form.cleaned_data['dog_name']
        form.dog_age = form.cleaned_data['dog_age']
        form.service_type = form.cleaned_data['service_type']
        form.training_place = form.cleaned_data['training_place']
        form.contact_date = form.cleaned_data['contact_date']
        form.source = form.cleaned_data['source']
        form.status = form.cleaned_data['status']
        form.notes = form.cleaned_data['notes']"""
        form.save()
        return redirect('xxx')

    return render(request, 'xxx', {'form' : form})
```

I would like some fields to be automatically filled in from the database with data, I have already tried various ways but to no avail
What I wrote above for some reason does not fill the fields for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial values you pass with `initial=...` are only displayed for "unbound forms", i.e. forms not having request data. Since you pass `request.POST` or even `None` that do not work. The usual idiom is:

```py
if request.method == "POST":
    # May skip passing initial here unless you use `form.has_changed()`
    form = CustomerForm(request.POST, initial=initial)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect(...)
else:
    form = CustomerForm(initial=initial)

# pass either an invalid or a new form to template ...
```

If you need to pass initial values from a model instance it usually makes sense to use a `ModelForm` and use `instance=...` instead of `initial=...`.

Comment: Just the values ​​I want to give are with lists of another model and I want to use them in another case to autocomplete it

Comment: Ok, i have data on form if i delete in form = CustomerForm(initial=initial) but i can't send this data to db :/

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_customer(request, pk=None):
form = CustomerForm(request.POST or None)
if request.method == 'GET':
    if pk is not None:
        instance = Contact.objects.get(pk=pk)
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
elif request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Klient został pomyślnie utworzony')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('xxx'))

return render(request, 'xxx', {'form': form})
```

I changed the whole concept, sent a link to the get to view methods where I used the method from a friend who posted here.
The optional parameter is because the function serves as a normal addition without a parameter as well
Regards and thanks for your help